# Как сокращают слово "японский"?

Tags: орфография

Как сокращают слово "японский"?

Answer (score 1):

Правильное сокращение: **яп. и япон.**

Можно **проверить**  https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#ya

Сокращение всегда делается после **согласной**, но не после **гласной.** Вероятно, согласные информационно более **значимы**, чем гласные.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "японский" сокращают как "яп.".

Answer (score 0):

В «[***Русском орфографическом словаре***](https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#ya)» приведены приведены такие основные общепринятые сокращения слова *японский*: ***яп.*** и ***япон.***

**P. S.**

Не согласен с утверждением одного из отвечавших в этой теме, что «*сокращение всегда делается после **согласной**, но не после **гласной***».

**Утверждение это ошибочно.**

См., к примеру, такие сокращения из числа общепринятых, приведённых в «***Русском орфографическом словаре***»:

***а. е.*** (астрономическая единица), ***о.*** (озеро), ***ю.*** (юг, южный)…

https://popravilam.com/blog/sokrashcheniya-osnovnye.html#ya